# Passing class function pointer to another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have the follow:

```
typedef void(*ptrFcn)(); //also I tried typedef void(B::*ptrFcn)()
class A {
....
void call(ptrFcn Fcn);
...
}
```

Until here, there is no problem..a simple definition of a class

```
class B{
A var;
...
void theFunction();  //until here, there is no problem
void theCurse();     //this is the problem
}
----- B.cpp -------
void B:: theCurse(){
//a lot of instructions
//here, I need to invoke theFunction without be a static function
var.call(theFunction);  //<--- wrong
}
```

All these instructions work without using class, but is mandatory both classes :( I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Thank u :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a few changes:

1. Declare that `B` is a `class` before defining the `typedef` so you can declare a pointer to a member function:

   ```
   class B;
   typedef void (B::*ptrFcn)();
   ```
2. When calling `A::call()` you need to take the address of a fully qualified name:

   ```
   var.call(&B::theFunction);
   ```

Obviously for `B::theFunction` to be useful for `A` you'll also need to make a `B` object known.

Comment: Thanks Dietmar. Well, the 1) is necessary because it will not compile. Using 2) it works in `B.cpp`, but there is an error in `A.cpp` (in call function) where the `Fcn` variable is used. The error is **term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments**

Comment: You probably also need to make `B::theFunction()` `static`, because, otherwise, you can't call it without an object that is an instance of `B` or a subclass...

Comment: I solved the problem calling **Fcn** instead **Fcn()** (as I did). Now, I have others memory problem derived from using &B::Function. Thanks

Comment: Well, if `B` is static, all my variables must be static too. And there will be a mess in my code :)